# How do i pass just a the date (no time) into a method taking a DateTime Variable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, methods

I want to pass just the date not time into a parameter. I have tried DateTime.Now.Date but this just sets the time to midnight. Any Ideas??
Here is my code:

```
GetAppointmentsOnSelectedDate(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `DateTime` object has a [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property which returns a `DateTime` set to midnight of the parent object. If you change your code to this:

```
GetAppointmentsOnSelectedDate(DateTime.Now.Date);
```

and modify `GetAppointmentsOnSelectedDate` to only care about the `Date` component of the object it receives, that should do what you want. Of course, when converting to a string and displaying it in the UI you'll want to leave off the time component.

Strictly speaking, using the `.Date` property isn't necessary if `GetAppointmentsOnSelectedDate` doesn't look at the time component anyways.

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` is a data type; you cannot manipulate what it parts of the data it inherently "shows".  If you're looking to display it, you need to convert it to a string, e.g. via `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()`.

Comment: I'm not looking to display it, i want to check if the appointment is on todays date but i cant because of the time

Comment: mason just posted your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` structure does what it says - it stores a date along with time. If you need just the date portion, use the `Date` member property and simply ignore the time portion. Such an approach should work 99% of the time. The only caveat is serialization and deserialization in different time zones, which can cause your `DateTime` value to shift.

Alternatively, it should not be too hard to create your own `Date` structure.

Comment: Thats fine, but i am checking it against another date and if they are the same it returns true. However the time portion causes it to fail and return false

Comment: Just compare the Date property: ``if( date1.Date == date2.Date )``